# Nodejs Multi-threading or clustering?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, pm2, nodejs-cluster

i have been studying about nodejs. one on my colleagues wanted to make multi-threading in nodejs.
as we know that nodejs itself is single-threaded. it supports concept of workers.
so is it called multi-threading or clustering concept. like functionality that "pm2" package provides us?

i have been studying about it, and there is library "cluster".
is multi-threading possible in nodejs?